# least angle required to avoid intersection

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to create an avoidance system where circle A has to avoid circle B with as minimum angle as possible. My approach is to create an imaginary circle C of radius Ra + Rb from the center of circle B and the draw a tangent from center of circle A to circle C. With those 2 tangents, I can get the minimum angle required to avoid the circle. I will add the minimum angle to current angle if circle A to avoid the Circle B. Is it the right approach or I am missing something here?[image: Image describing my idea]

Comment: Even if you're supposed to use this for a programming assignment, the problem itself is more math than programming, and as such should be posted on [the math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, I will post it there. Thanks for pointing me towards correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the right approach.

You'll notice that the centers of the two circles and the tangent point make a right triangle. The sine of the angle you need is Ra+Rb divided by the distance between the circle centers. You can compute the angle with the `std::asin` function.

```
double angleInRadians = std::asin((Ra+Rb)/(Cb-Ca))
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this?[link](https://imgur.com/a/gWkMgdh?)

Comment: That's close, just remember to use the *inverse* sine function `asin` not the sine function "sin", be careful with the parentheses, and remember that the result is in radians not degrees